# android toast doesn't fit text

Tags: android, toast

I am developing an application where I have to use numerous toasts.

I display these toasts by using:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Some medium-sized text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The displayer toast, however, has the height of one line, while the text is displayed on multiple lines. The result is that I can't view all the text in the toast.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try inserting a carriage-return and line-feed where you want to split the text.

These characters refer back to the old typewriter models.  Carriage return was the cylinder moving back to the start and line feed was the cylinder rolling (feeding) by one line.

In computing these are represented by two escaped characters (special codes that allow non-printable codes inside a string by prefixing them with a backslash `\`).

- A carriage return is represented by `\r`
- A line-feed is represented by `\n` (you can remember this as a new line).

Some non-unix systems (e.g. Windows) require both, others (e.g Linux on which Android is based) only need the new line but it is generally safe to do both everywhere.  The one thing that is essential is the order they are in.  It must be `\r\n`

To put this into your example:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "First line of text\r\nSecond line of text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In Android you should be able to reduce this to just the new line character `\n` as unix based systems are not so fussy:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "First line of text\nSecond line of text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and detailed explanations. The toast dimensions now fit the text.

Comment: That idea seems not work if the string in the toast message comes from PHP echo, if for example you have echo "fist line\nsecond line", your app will show a toast message with "fist linesecond line", which is a bad thing, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the main idea of this [Custom toast in android : a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example) and this [Android's Toast default colors and alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262769/androids-toast-default-colors-and-alpha) I developed a simple custom Toast that looks like the default one but it wraps the text in multilines.

I create a simple class with the `makeText(context,text,duration)` static method, so I had only to replace `Toast.makeText` with `CustomToast.makeText` everywhere in my projects.

Below the code

`CustomToast.java`

```
public class CustomToast extends Toast{
    /**
     * Construct an empty Toast object.  You must call {@link #setView} before you
     * can call {@link #show}.
     *
     * @param context The context to use.  Usually your {@link Application}
     *                or {@link Activity} object.
     */
    public CustomToast(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(text);

        t.setView(layout);


        return t;
    }

}
```

The layout `layout/custom_toast.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout_id"
              android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
              android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
        android:shadowRadius="2.75"/>

</LinearLayout>
```