# Custom toast message in all screens?

Tags: android, android-toast

I have developed one application which has 15 screens. Now I want to display custom toast message in all those 15 screens. To do so, I have inflated one layout. But it's working only on one screen. So, I wrote a single method to display custom `Toast` on all screens. Whenever I want to display toast message, I would just call that method. But i got `java.lang.NullPointerException`. How to resolve this? The following is my code,

```
public static void showToastMessage(String message){

               LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                  (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.customToast));
            // set a message
                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText(message);

                // Toast...
                Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
           }
```

Log is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.guayama.utilities.CommonMethods.showToastMessage(CommonMethods.java:474)

    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)

    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)

    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)

    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: and your logcat error report?

Comment: I know, but you didn't post the line numbers, so you have to tell us which line is line 474. Anyway, all the answers below are the same and I also believe that your problem is the static variable context. You should avoid static variables in Android by all means. Pass context in as a parameter.

Comment: [Heads Up, Updates to toasts in Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61608646/4694013)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change your method

from

```
showToastMessage(String message)
```

to

```
showToastMessage(Context context,String message);
```

it seems context problem to me

your function will look like this

```
public static void showToastMessage(Context context,String message){

               LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                  (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.customToast));
            // set a message
                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText(message);

                // Toast...
                Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
           }
```

Comment: This will work,But static  method will leads to memory leak

Answer (score 5):

A custom class implementation of Toast that can be used in any project.

```
public class ToastMessage {
        private Context context;
        private static ToastMessage instance;

    /**
     * @para
   m context
     */
    private ToastMessage(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public synchronized static ToastMessage getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ToastMessage(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param message
     */
    public void showLongMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * @param message
     */
    public void showSmallMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * The Toast displayed via this method will display it for short period of time
     *
     * @param message
     */
    public void showLongCustomToast(String message) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_toast));
        TextView msgTv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
        msgTv.setText(message);
        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();

    }

    /**
     * The toast displayed by this class will display it for long period of time
     *
     * @param message
     */
    public void showSmallCustomToast(String message) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_toast));
        TextView msgTv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
        msgTv.setText(message);
        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can this also be used to show attached to a recyclerview in a layout?

Answer (score 2):

pass `Context` in and use it as `showToastMessage(String message,Context context)`

thus:

```
public static void showToastMessage(String message){
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
   (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.customToast));
   // set a message
   TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
   text.setText(message);

   // Toast...
   Toast toast = new Toast(context);
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
   toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setView(layout);
   toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem,

```
(Activity) context
```

You have not passed the context object to this method and you are trying to refer some Context Object which you could have declared globally.

So at this point if your Context Object is null you will get NullPointer. Try to pass the conetxt of your Current Activity in the parameter of your showToastMessage()

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on custom toast so please follow the below process and you will use the common method for multiple time.

My custom_toast.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="25dp"
       >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/custom_toast_image"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custom_toast_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="16dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Second thing create one java class: like CustomToast.java

```
public class CustomToast {
Context context;



public static void showToastMessage(Context context,String message){

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,
            (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
    // set a message
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_message);
    text.setText(message);

    // Toast...
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

Third step create the object of CustomToast.java class in your activity and call the method by passing context and message.

```
 CustomToast customToast=new CustomToast();
  customToast.showToastMessage(ctx,message);
```