# How can I transform this into a method/class so it can be reusable?

Tags: java, android

I want to use this in lots of places in my code and there will be a lot of repetition, but my knowledge in java is not sufficient enough to make this work.

```
        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_USER_NAME_MIN_LENGTH_PROBLEM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
        myToast.show();
```

I wanna be able to use it this way:

```
ToastMaker(short duration (//or long), configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGE (//of my choice), configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR(//or some other variable), configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND_COLOR(//or some other variable), 30(//text size), gravity)

something like this
ToastMaker(length, errorMessage, textColor, backgroundColor, textSize, gravity)
```

the one thing that concerns me the most is that the following piece of code is going to change for every class, and I do not know how to obtain that dynamically

```
net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this
```

Actually I can make the text color, size and background a general setting for the entire app (which makes sense), so we are left with this:

```
ToastMaker(length, errorMessage, gravity)
```

as the final desired result

EDIT: I've answered my question with the working code, that I generated after reading all the answers

Comment: replace `net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this` with a parameter of type `Context` and let each place that calls the method put in e.g. `net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this`

Comment: Re-factor the code such that all the common repeating code could go into methods, and invoke the methods via parameters.

Comment: Im sorry guys, these explanations are very abstract to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

I putted in runOnUi() method so you can call it from Asynctask/background thread

**For long time**

```
 public void tong(Context mContext, final String msg) {
            ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
                    tv.setTextSize(20);
                    myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
                    myToast.show();
                }
            });
        }
```

**For short time**

```
public void ting(final Context mContext, final String msg) {

            ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
                    tv.setTextSize(20);
                    myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
                    myToast.show();
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if want to declare it in saperet class the

```
class YourClass{

  public void showToast(Context context){

    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(context, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_USER_NAME_MIN_LENGTH_PROBLEM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
    myToast.show();
  }
}
```

use in other class like this

```
YourClass myClass=new YourClass();
myClass.showToast(mContext);
```

You can also pass other parameter with context (e.g. message).

Answer (score 1):

How about make one static method like:

```
public static void ToastMaker(length, errorMessage, textColor, backgroundColor, textSize, gravity)
```

Need to add context as parameter though. Just put your code in that method and that about it. You may even use custom layout

refer to this link: [Custom toast message in all screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339980/custom-toast-message-in-all-screens)

Hope this makes it bit more clear.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

you can simple use this:

1) First make a Common class named **DisplayToast**.

```
and in this class make method like 


public void showToast(Context context){

 Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(context, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_USER_NAME_MIN_LENGTH_PROBLEM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
 TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
 tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
 tv.setTextSize(20);
myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
 myToast.show();
}
```

Now whenever you want to access this method in any class then you should make object of this class like:

```
 DisplayToast dt = new DisplayToast();
```

now call that method

```
 dt.showToast(context);
```

2) You can also make static method for that like:

```
 public static void showToast(Context context){

 Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(context, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_USER_NAME_MIN_LENGTH_PROBLEM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
 TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
 tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
 tv.setTextSize(20);
myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
 myToast.show();
}
```

And you can use this in your class like

```
 DisplayToast.showToast(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, thanks to your help, this is what I created and it works perfectly:

```
public class ToastMaker extends Activity {

    public void toast(Context context, final String message, Configurationz configurationz, int duration) {

                Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(context, message , duration);
                myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                TextView tv = (TextView) myToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_TEXT_COLOR));
                tv.setTextSize(configurationz.TOAST_TEXT_SIZE);
                myToast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(configurationz.COLORS_TOAST_BACKGROUND));
                myToast.show();
    }
}
```

Im using it this way:

```
ToastMaker toastMaker = new ToastMaker();

toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_USER_NAME_MIN_LENGTH_PROBLEM, configurationz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```