# How to show a top bar message in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications

I want to show this kind of message in Android top after finishing some background work.
How do I show this kind of notification ?
Thanks..

[image]

Comment: Use custom toast, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example

Comment: What stops you using a TextView aligned to the Parent's top, with a left compound drawable inside? Normally it would be INVISIBLE and then you make it visible only when required.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like the ticker text of a `Notification`, assuming that this screenshot is of the top of the screen. You can add that to the `Notification` via [`setTicker()` on your `NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). Note, though, that ticker text is no longer displayed as of API Level 21 (Android 5.0). Also note that ticker text automatically disappears after a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Notification alert, this can be started from services, activities,fragments, broadcaster receivers,etc...
Check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

This example was copied from google dev:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Build a notification and use setTicker (Look at the doc [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTicker(java.lang.CharSequence)))) :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventLocation)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .setTicker("Your message");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW which will show message always on Top whether your application is foreground or background.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.TOP;

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(view, params);





<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```