# Different toast messages in Android

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-context, android-toast

In my Android application I get two different types of Toast message by giving `getApplicationContext()` and `MainActivity.this`

Method 1:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No more items.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

produce the following output:

[image]

Method 2:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No more items.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

second method produce the following toast message which differ from the first one.

[image]

I do not know the reason between `getApplicationContext()` and `MainActivity.this` for producing two different toast messages. please share reason behind the difference.

I run under Android `Kitkat 4.4.2` in `Samsung S4.`

Comment: that depending api version of mobie

Comment: The first Toast is Samsung-4.2+ like. The second one is the one from Android, intended to be used. Use the second one, not the first.

Comment: Nothing is wrong here. There are too may reasons of this output (BUT not these both contexts). Check if both apps min API level is same.

Comment: Either develop your custom Toast : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is themed by Samsungs' TouchWiz UI

Answer (score 3):

getapplication context return the context of the application which remain same throughout the application. But .this context returns the context specific to the activity.