# Can't create a custom toast

Tags: android, class, nullpointerexception, toast

I'm having the same issues getting a custom toast class for reuse in any activity.

I get a `null pointer exception` or a `invoke findviewbyid method` error no matter what I try. please help

```
class Toaster extends Activity {
Toaster(Context context, String message) {

    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)context.findViewById(R.id.toastroot));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);

        text.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();

    }
}}
```

Comment: What does the xml for R.id.toast_layout look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way to have thins kind of functionality in an `Activity`.

Instead you could use a class with static methods to do it for you, like this:

```
 public final class Toaster {

   public static void showToast(final Context context, String message) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)context.findViewById(R.id.toastroot));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);

    text.setText(message);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
     }

  }
```

Then, you would make calls like this:

```
 Toaster.showToast(context,"some message");
```

Comment: Thank you! Very close now...Activity not liking the context being passed and the toaster class is not liking the context.findviewbyid...those two errors related?..Im guessing ive got the wrong context. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand

Comment: Toaster.showToast(getApplicationcontext(),"some message"); is the one that will pass into Toast.showtoast.  My problem now is that context.findview by id ...findview by id has error

Comment: Remove that context.findviewById. You don't need that to inflate your view.

Comment: class toaster is external class of its own correct? not in the activity's

Comment: Yes, it is another class in a different file

Comment: View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)context.findViewById(R.id.toastroot));

Comment: View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) (R.id.toastroot));    ???

Comment: All this flippin messin around. Studio complained about null. It works perfectly. Thank you very much.vinitius

Comment: Man can yoa take a look at some of my other questions by chance? Lol don't seem to be getting much feed back

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are extending Activity. You never construct an activity directly, so constructor here is pointless.
If you are trying to make custom Toast message try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288522/2180461

Edit:
To be more specific about why are you getting NPE:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)context.findViewById(R.id.toastroot));
```

You are casting context to ViewGroup, and than using it to find `R.id.toastroot` inside that ViewGroup. Most probably - context here is null, so that's the origin of your Exception.

Comment: You are definitely correct. FindByID doesnt work by itself for whatever reason. I have tried every combination  I can think of. I'm missing something here. Goal is to be able to call this toast class from any of my 3 activities and just send a different message into it.