# How to change Toast Location at the Top in android

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to change toast location bottom to Top as below picture:-

[image]

In this picture "Added to Cart" show in Top. I Want same as. I see many questions same as but I can't find right solution. Anyone can help me.

Comment: you can set gravity for that toast object.

Comment: and what about right mark and arrow mark

Comment: You have to create a custom toast..to show right and arrow marks.

Comment: YFI..checkout this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example

Comment: set gravity of  Toast .                                                                                                eg.                                                                                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
       toast.show();