# Problems during Custom toast

Tags: android

I am creating a custom toast but it is not working at all.

This is my Code:-

```
private void showCustomToast(String showToast) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(showToast);
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(inflater);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: in setView method, you need to set the layout not the inflater object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example

Comment: @Amy #Nigam this account suspected .Please check #user6038645 all question and see who get #Accepted answer . # voting irregularities

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thank you. Got it

Comment: @Amy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863377/problems-during-resize-the-spinner-in-android

Comment: #user6038645  & SVJ Welcome to #So .Please read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass **layout** object in the `setView()` method not the **inflater**.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your `setView` section. Pass `View` **Object** .

**Don't**

```
toast.setView(inflater);
```

**Do**

```
 toast.setView(layout);
```

**Finally**

```
 private void showCustomToast(String showToast) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(showToast);
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout); // Not inflater
        toast.show();
    }
```