# Java Android create canvas that will pop-up automatically at a specified date

Tags: java, android, canvas, alarmmanager, toast

I am developing a simple android app that manages events(An event contains a name, a description, and a **date**). For example: Somebody's birthday or something like that.

I want a canvas to pop up by itself at the specified date(even if I'm not in the application). I managed to create a Toast using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver which pop ups automatically at the specified date. But I can only write text to a Toast.
Is there any way to create a canvas that will pop up similar to a Toast?

My **alarm manager**:

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ALARM_ACTION");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

Intent intent = new Intent("ALARM_ACTION");
intent.putExtra("param", "It's your mom's birthday!");
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000,operation) ;
```

And my **Receiver** class:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //I want to replace the Toast with a canvas.
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("param"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the following link: [toast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-in-android-a-simple-example)

Comment: And how can I create that custom toast in my Receiver class? Because it's not an activity and I can't call methods like findViewById for example.

Comment: @BillJobs you have a `Context` parameter. Which means you can get a `LayoutInflator` using `getSystemService()` and inflate any view you want. The view allows you to  call `findViewById()` on to customize it. And then you can pass the View to the Toast.