# how to create a confirmation view like android toast

Tags: android, android-toast

need to pop up a confirmation "toast" and wait for the clicking on "Done" to dismiss it.

saw post [Customview like Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565608/customview-like-toast), but that has the android toast's auto dismiss behavior.

The android toast's position is what needed, but how to make it stay and taking the user clicking.

something like [image]

But has a "Done" clickable text in the right.

like [icon | lable | Done].

Comment: Have you ever heard of Snackbar?

Comment: need to float the view above the bottom but not touch the bottom edge, and not cover the whole width. like the toast's default position behavior

Comment: @lannyf That's exactly what `Snackbar` looks like: https://material.io/components/snackbars

Comment: @Same Chen Thanks! But having problem to use snackbar here where it is deep down in a notification handler class only have access to the Context.  It does not have a 'view' for making the snackBar.