# Toast message text alignment out of box

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-toast

I'm displaying toast messsage from async-task on postexecute but it displaying not proper like below image.
Anyone can help me please.

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Stamp Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

Comment: first, paste your code and does Toast work properly when you call it in a different position and different devices?

Comment: @EliasFazel in some device it works properly

Comment: I encountered this problem on past and solved using **applicationContext** instead of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom toast message. 
follow the below link.

Please See this Link
[See more from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-on-android-a-simple-example/30411107)
copied from this link.

toast.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#DAAA" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout); 
toast.show();
```

Comment: yeah good solution but what is the problem with that system Toast view?