# Can I access Android toast XML that created during runtime?

Tags: android, testing, toast

I need to access the created Toast XML code that has been displayed at runtime for testing purposes. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288522/1129995

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but i need to do that without using custom toast

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Toast messages programmatically, like this in Java:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

And in Kotlin:

```
val text = "Hello toast!"
val duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, duration)
toast.show()
```

I think u can use this like a function to testing.

Also, if you want to know about Toast message much more, please follow a link to Android Developers Blog: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#kotlin

Comment: Thank you so much but i need to access the created xml code that has been created during the run time so that it can appears when doing automation testing!

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
View toastView = toast.getView();
```

Comment: Thank you so mush for your help but i still need more clarification ,, how can i access the xml code of that toast?

Comment: if you want to access any view reference of the toast view, then it would be better to go for custom toast . See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-on-android-a-simple-example