# Why do toasts get truncated when app is installed on Android 12 APi 31

Tags: java, android, android-toast, android-12

The documentation says that Toasts are truncated to two lines on applications *targeting* Android 12 or later. The behaviour that I observe is that Toasts are truncated to two lines on applications *installed* on a device running Android 12 or later.

Specifically, one of my apps which was installed *before* my phone was updated to Android 12 does not get its toasts truncated, but if I install it on the emulator running Android 12 it gets its toasts truncated. Another app which I rebuilt and installed *after* my phone was updated to Android 12 gets its toasts truncated.

**Update:**

The situation appears actually to be more complicated: the behaviour also depends on the device and apparently also on whether it's a debug or a release build. The same app which was getting its toasts truncated displays them correctly with a release build on my phone, but truncates them with the *same* release build on the emulator.

Note that this is not the same question as [70307699](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307699/android-12-as-of-targetsdkversion-31-the-toast-messages-are-clipped) where the OP updated his `targetSdk` to 31. Both my apps have `targetSdk` set to less than 31.

How can I get the documented behaviour and get my toasts back?

Answer (score 7):

Rather than outright deprecating toasts, the Android Platform Team is instead making them progressively less useful, which is a form of deprecation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast

The last sentence states: `Starting with Android 12 (API level 31), apps targeting Android 12 or newer will have their toasts limited to two lines.`

Going forward I'll personally be using Snackbars if I need a multi-line message.

```
val SNACKBAR_MAX_LINES = 8 // Increase maximum SnackBar line limit above 2
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(bottomNavigationView, "message", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            (snackbar.view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView)
                .run {
                    maxLines = SNACKBAR_MAX_LINES 
                }

snackbar.show()
```

Comment: My app doesn't *target* API 31 or later, so its behaviour shouldn't be changed by installing it on a device with API 31. I use a lot of toasts, so it would be major surgery to change them to snackbars, and would probably make my app not work on older versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be a work around. Try creating a custom toast message. I tried creating one with `PopupWindow`. The `setContentView` method of this class can be used to set custom layout and thereby can support multiple lines of text.

[Custom toast on Android: a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-on-android-a-simple-example/75611820#75611820)

And if you want to make it a generic one by creating a method in Application Class of your app. Here is the code.

```
class ApplicationClass() : Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private var activityReference: Activity? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
    }

    fun showCustomToast(toast: String) {
        try {
            activityReference?.window?.decorView?.let {
                val popupWindow = PopupWindow(it.width - 200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                val binding = GenericToastPopupBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
                binding.toastMessage.text = toast
                popupWindow.contentView = binding.root
                binding.close.setOnClickListener {
                    popupWindow.dismiss()
                }
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.bg_rectangle_white
                    )
                )
                popupWindow.animationStyle = android.R.style.Animation_Toast
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(it, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 500)
                MainScope().launch {
                    delay(5000)
                    popupWindow.dismiss()
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "showCustomToast: ")
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        activityReference = activity
    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        activityReference = activity
    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        activityReference = activity
    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
       
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
       
    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {
     
    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
      
    }
}
```