# Remove icon from Toast (Android 12)

Tags: android, toast

Is it possible to remove icon from Toast message in Android 12 (API level 31) or higher?

I don't prefer using a snackbar instead of using a toast.

Comment: You can't. This is the default behavior of Toast on Android 12.

Comment: I am not sure but may be try [custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-on-android-a-simple-example) for toast ?

Comment: @Manohar custom layout for toast deprecated

Comment: @Stanley yeah my bad.